# I want to replace the url_for() call entirely

Tags: python, flask

I've had tremendous success using the following tutorial to stream a sequence of JPEG images from OpenCV using Flask: https://www.aranacorp.com/en/stream-video-from-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-web-browser/

Using that tutorial, I am able to render the JPEG image sequence processed by OpenCV in my client HTML document by using the following code:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" />
```

However, in my use case, I would prefer to consume the images using the following schema:

```
<img src"ip.address.of.server/filename.jpg" />
```

How do I provision OpenCV in Flask to accomplish this?

***NOTE:** I am new to Python, so please forgive me for the "dumb question".

Comment: pure flask question. (1) change the `@app.route` decoration (2) change the HTML code (3) done.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I should mention that I am new at Python and Flask. Could you provide some code syntax as an example, please?

Comment: If you just want the url to be absolute rather than relative then add `_external=True` as a keyword argument when you call `url_for`.

Comment: @EAW That's the thing: I'm trying NOT to use the `url_for` method whatsoever.

Comment: If you don’t want to use the the flask routing system then you’ll need to hard code the url into the html page exactly as you have already done in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Being new to Python, as per @EAW, it turns out that all I have to do is use the server's IP address and file path of the JPEG image file itself, just as I had supposed in my example schema.